# Play specific html5 audio file if element is visible on screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, audio, css-animations

I have a set of animated elements that move across a div.

[Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/th2u8h6a/)

```
<div class="static-parent">
    <div class="animated-child animated-one"></div>
    <div class="animated-child animated-two"></div>
</div>

.static-parent{
    height:10em;
    width:20em;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;   
    overflow:hidden;
}

.animated-child{
    height:5em;
    width:5em;
    position:absolute;
}

.animated-one{
    -webkit-animation: 5s moving linear infinite; 
    background-color:green;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moving{
    0% {
        left:-5em;
    }
    100% {
        left: -webkit-calc(100% + 5em);
    }

}

.animated-two{
    -webkit-animation: 5s moving-two linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay:2s;
    background-color:blue;
    left:-5em;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moving-two{
    0% {
        left:-5em;
    }
    100% {
        left: -webkit-calc(100% + 5em);
    }

}
```

When each of these elements enter the div, I would like to play an html5 audio file that is specific to each animated element. So the blue and green squares would contain different sounds. Once these elements animate off of the screen, I would like their sounds to stop. Etc etc...

Can this be done in simple jquery? Any and all help -- thank you very much in advance.